# GTKSourceView "style not defined" when loading a file with custom .lang file

Tags: gtksourceview

I edited the default markdown.lang file to add different colored headers depending on the level. This works, but whenever I launch a file (with mousepad) from the teminal, I get a bunch of warnings of the format:

```
(mousepad:3981174): GtkSourceView-WARNING **: 16:39:39.203: in file /usr/share/gtksourceview-4/language-specs/markdown.lang: style 'def:header6' not defined
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. In the markdown.lang file I have added parts like this:

```
<context id="header6" style-ref="header6">
      <match>(?&lt;=^###### ).+</match>
    </context>
```

And then:

```
    <context ref="header6"/>
```

and:

```
<style id="header6" name="Header" map-to="def:header6"/>
```

In the theme files I just add lines like this:

```
  <style name="def:header6"               foreground="#b6b3eb" bold="true"/>
```

I'm not exactly what I need to add to either the .lang file or the theme file to remove the warnings.